# Boxplot next to a scatterplot in R with plotly

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot, r-plotly

I created a scatter plot with plotly in R. Now I want to plot a boxplot with different data next to the scatter plot. I want to use plotly for this.

The result should look like [this](http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.de/2013/04/rg6-xy-scatter-plot-with-box-plot-at.html). Can someone help me please, I have no idea how to do that.
My code so far is

```
plot_ly(ds, x = ~x, y = ~y , mode = "markers", name = "Clusters", opacity = point.opacity, 
           text = ds$id,
           hoverinfo = "text",
           marker = list(symbol = point.symbol, color = ~color, size = point.size, 
                         line = list(color = "#262626", width = point.linewidth, opacity = point.lineopacity)),
           showlegend = F)
```

Comment: In the linked example image, the marginal boxplots illustrate the distribution of x and y plotted in the scatter plot. Are you after that in plotly or just two graphs side by side? Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a reproducible example. I have a scatter plot of the cross validation set and want to have a boxplot of the trainings set next to the scatter plot of the cross validation set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to make a scatter with marginal box plots with plotly:

```
library(plotly)
data(iris)
```

create, three plots for the data: one for the scatter, two for the appropriate box plots, and one additional empty plot. Use the subplot function to arrange them:

```
subplot(
  plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Petal.Length, type = 'box'),
  plotly_empty(),
  plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, type = 'scatter',
          mode = 'markers'),
  plot_ly(data = iris, y = ~Petal.Width, type = 'box'),
  nrows = 2, heights = c(.2, .8), widths = c(.8,.2), margin = 0,
  shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE) %>%
  layout(showlegend = F)
```

[image]

Comment: @Jensxy So you made a question without a reproducible example, linked an image of the desired result without data. I provided the code to produce the same kind of graphic using the desired package and now in your comment you post you would like to add something that you haven't mentioned anywhere  previously? Without data. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547448/r-for-the-same-code-labels-q1-median-appear-on-one-computer-but-dont-appea thanks!